# Two-way binding is not recognising variable change in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, 2-way-object-databinding

I have a slider that is used to changed a value in my controller like so

index:

```
            <div>
                <rzslider
                     rz-slider-model="slider.value"
                     rz-slider-options="slider.options">
                </rzslider>
                     <p>{{slider.value}}</p>
            </div>
```

controller:

```
app.controller('gbarchartController', function($scope) {
$scope.slider = {
          value: 20,
          options: {
            floor: 0,
            ceil: 30
          }
        };
```

When i change the value of the slider, the code below displays it on screen as 2 way binding should.

```
<p>{{slider.value}}</p>
```

The problem is , if i try to access this variable through a function in my controller, it uses the initial value of 20 that has been set. eg. If i change the slider to 10, the below code still uses the value 20. the variable in question is $scope.slider.value . The value is used to cut the length of an array, that in turn is used to display a graph using highchart.js.

```
            $scope.graph = function(metric) {
        Highcharts.chart(metric, {

            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Number Of Executions'
            },
            colors: [
                     '#7CFC00', '#FF0000'
                     ],

            xAxis: {
                categories: numExe.hash.slice(0, $scope.slider.value),
                title: {
                    text: 'Query Hash Value'
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: '% of Total Executions'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                shared:true
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Baseline',
                data: numExe.base.slice(0, $scope.slider.value)
            },
            {
                name: 'Comparative',
                data: numExe.compare.slice(0, $scope.slider.value)
            }]
        });

    }
```

Long story short, The variable changes in the html but does not change in the controller. Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Would be easier to check if you could post a jsfiddle or codepen or something.

Comment: @TheRodeo I would post one but the data generated comes from a local server and I have to spend hours fixing it to work with local data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Highcharts monitors its data for changes, so it won't detect changes to your series data (see [docs here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.redraw)). Additionally the series data passed in to the graph is static, so it won't update after the slider changes. You'll need to create a local [Series](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series) variable to hold the series data, and update the series data when the slider changes. I'm not sure what numExe is so I can't say how the data is generated, but the Series object has setData() method (with a redraw parameter) that should do the trick.